# Xcode: Page-based application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

I want to make a book application using the new page-based app of Xcode 4.2 but I'm kinda lost, I'm a bit confused with it.

For my first try I want to put different images per page, just to be familiar with it, how should I do that?

I haven't coded anything yet because I don't know where to start.

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered here. I'd recommend reading a book or watching the iOS dev lectures Stanford has on iTunesU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where to start learning about `UIPageViewController`:

[*View Controller Catalog for iOS:* “Page View Controllers”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH4-SW3)
The last 15 minutes of [WWDC 2011 Videos: Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/)
[Techtopia: An Example iOS 5 iPhone UIPageViewController Application](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application)