# XCode 4.2: How To Use Page-Based Application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

I am trying to explore xcode 4.2, and now i am trying to build a simple book app using the page-based app template on xcode.

I actually have no idea how things go on page-based app. to practice i want to load 1 image (different image each page) in every page. it's just a simple picture look book just for me to learn and be familiar how will i able to work with page-based application.

I am a bit confused with it, i don't know where to start. how will i able to do that??

any links for reference? or books that tackles the page-based application??

Comment: AS you have mentioned You are using the XCode 4.2 for development.there is separate template named As PageBasedApplication.
you should start from that Template.it'll gives some code along with that template.

Comment: yes, that's what i am asking for... i don't know how to manipulate it, i just want to load different images in each page.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on UIPageViewController? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode: Page-based application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424629/xcode-page-based-application)

Comment: +1 because I don't like others downvoting questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a book by Wei-Meng Lee called 'Beginning iOS 5 Application Development" he has online source code free for book owners. It's located here: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-iOS-5-Application-Development.productCd-1118144252,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html

In the FULL DOWNLOAD there is an app called UsingViews (UsingViews.zip). That app shows you how to move through views. I highly recommend purchasing his book. Very Helpful.

Apple Documentation is also very helpful as others have already pointed out.